# No Such table in API 2.2

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-2.2-froyo

Everything goes successful in my app in higher versions, but in the lower versions like 2.2 the app crashes while fetching data from database with this error

```
07-17 21:46:36.361: I/Database(520): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such table: Schedules
07-17 21:46:36.371: W/System.err(520): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: Schedules: , while compiling: SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Schedules
07-17 21:46:36.391: W/System.err(520):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
07-17 21:46:36.391: W/System.err(520):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:91)
07-17 21:46:36.401: W/System.err(520):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:64)
07-17 21:46:36.462: W/System.err(520):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:80)
07-17 21:46:36.462: W/System.err(520):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:46)
07-17 21:46:36.485: W/System.err(520):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:42)
07-17 21:46:36.492: W/System.err(520):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1345)
07-17 21:46:36.492: W/System.err(520):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1315)
07-17 21:46:36.502: W/System.err(520):  at com.example.indianconstitution.DBAdapter.getSchedules(DBAdapter.java:148)
07-17 21:46:36.502: W/System.err(520):  at com.example.indianconstitution.SchedulesFragment.onCreate(SchedulesFragment.java:37)
07-17 21:46:36.502: W/System.err(520):  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1477)
07-17 21:46:36.512: W/System.err(520):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:904)
07-17 21:46:36.512: W/System.err(520):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1115)
07-17 21:46:36.512: W/System.err(520):  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
07-17 21:46:36.521: W/System.err(520):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1478)
07-17 21:46:36.521: W/System.err(520):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:446)
07-17 21:46:36.521: W/System.err(520):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-17 21:46:36.521: W/System.err(520):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-17 21:46:36.521: W/System.err(520):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-17 21:46:36.521: W/System.err(520):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-17 21:46:36.521: W/System.err(520):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-17 21:46:36.552: W/System.err(520):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-17 21:46:36.552: W/System.err(520):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-17 21:46:36.571: W/System.err(520):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-17 21:46:36.571: W/System.err(520):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-17 21:46:36.661: D/AndroidRuntime(520): Shutting down VM
07-17 21:46:36.661: W/dalvikvm(520): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
07-17 21:46:36.691: E/AndroidRuntime(520): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-17 21:46:36.691: E/AndroidRuntime(520): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-17 21:46:36.691: E/AndroidRuntime(520):  at com.example.indianconstitution.SchedulesAdapter.<init>(SchedulesAdapter.java:22)
07-17 21:46:36.691: E/AndroidRuntime(520):  at com.example.indianconstitution.SchedulesFragment.onCreateView(SchedulesFragment.java:58)
07-17 21:46:36.691: E/AndroidRuntime(520):  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
07-17 21:46:36.691: E/AndroidRuntime(520):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:938)
07-17 21:46:36.691: E/AndroidRuntime(520):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1115)
07-17 21:46:36.691: E/AndroidRuntime(520):  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
07-17 21:46:36.691: E/AndroidRuntime(520):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1478)
07-17 21:46:36.691: E/AndroidRuntime(520):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:446)
07-17 21:46:36.691: E/AndroidRuntime(520):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-17 21:46:36.691: E/AndroidRuntime(520):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-17 21:46:36.691: E/AndroidRuntime(520):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-17 21:46:36.691: E/AndroidRuntime(520):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-17 21:46:36.691: E/AndroidRuntime(520):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
07-17 21:46:36.691: E/AndroidRuntime(520):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-17 21:46:36.691: E/AndroidRuntime(520):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-17 21:46:36.691: E/AndroidRuntime(520):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-17 21:46:36.691: E/AndroidRuntime(520):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-17 21:46:36.892: D/dalvikvm(520): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 3629 objects / 277352 bytes in 181ms
```

This link http://www.anddev.org/networking-database-problems-f29/missing-table-in-sqlite-with-specific-version-of-desire-hd-t50364.html suggests that there are some problems in phones like htc desire but I am facing this problem in spice mi-270(2.2) & also in emulators 2.1,2.2 !

I am using this code as my DBAdapter class

```
public class DBAdapter extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
//CustomAdapter adapter;
static String name = "law6.sqlite";
static String path = "";
static ArrayList<GS> gs;
static SQLiteDatabase sdb;

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
{
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
} 

private DBAdapter(Context v) 
{
    super(v, name, null, 1);
    path = "/data/data/" + v.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + "/databases";
}

public boolean checkDatabase()
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = null;
    try 
    {
        db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path + "/" + name, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    } catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (db == null) 
    {
        return false;
    } 
    else
    {
        db.close();
        return true;
    }
}

public static synchronized DBAdapter getDBAdapter(Context v)
{
    return (new DBAdapter(v));
}

public void createDatabase(Context v) throws IOException
{
    this.getReadableDatabase();
    try
    {
        InputStream myInput = v.getAssets().open(name);
        // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = path +"/"+ name;
        // Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) 
    {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
        // Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

    } catch (IOException e) 
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}

public void openDatabase() 
{
    try 
    {
        sdb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path + "/" + name, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    } catch (Exception e) 
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}

    public ArrayList<GS> getSchedules() 
{
    try{
    Cursor c1 = sdb.query(true,"Schedules",null,null,null,null,null,null,null);//rawQuery("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Schedules", null);
    gs = new ArrayList<GS>();
    while (c1.moveToNext())
    {
        GS q1 = new GS();
        q1.setS_name(c1.getString(1));
        q1.setP_name(c1.getString(2));
        q1.setDesc(c1.getString(3));
        gs.add(q1);
    }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return gs;
}
}
```

I have tried using `query()` instead of `rawQuery()` but no help !

I think the problem could be in `createDatabase()` or `openDatabase()` relating `getReadableDatabase()` or I dont know what?

I am fetching this data using this

```
     DBAdapter db = DBAdapter.getDBAdapter(getActivity());

     if (!db.checkDatabase())
        try {
            db.createDatabase(getActivity());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

     db.openDatabase();

     s = db.getSchedules();
```

Any Idea...?

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE** This is the logging I found in Jelly bean, It is showing exception but workking fine

```
07-25 10:24:35.721: E/Trace(14495): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
07-25 10:24:37.351: I/Adreno200-EGL(14495): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:299>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: Nondeterministic AU_msm8625_REFS/TAGS/JB_REL_RB5_QRD_D20130221_CL3357771_release_AU (CL3357771)
07-25 10:24:37.351: I/Adreno200-EGL(14495): Build Date: 02/22/13 Fri
07-25 10:24:37.351: I/Adreno200-EGL(14495): Local Branch: 
07-25 10:24:37.351: I/Adreno200-EGL(14495): Remote Branch: m/refs/tags/jb_rel_rb5_qrd_D20130221
07-25 10:24:37.351: I/Adreno200-EGL(14495): Local Patches: NONE
07-25 10:24:37.351: I/Adreno200-EGL(14495): Reconstruct Branch: NOTHING
07-25 10:24:38.031: I/Choreographer(14495): Skipped 50 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-25 10:24:45.961: E/SQLiteLog(14495): (14) cannot open file at line 30178 of [00bb9c9ce4]
07-25 10:24:45.961: E/SQLiteLog(14495): (14) os_unix.c:30178: (2) open(/data/data/com.example.indianconstitution/databases/law6.sqlite) - 
07-25 10:24:45.981: E/SQLiteDatabase(14495): Failed to open database '/data/data/com.example.indianconstitution/databases/law6.sqlite'.
07-25 10:24:45.981: E/SQLiteDatabase(14495): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
07-25 10:24:45.981: E/SQLiteDatabase(14495):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
07-25 10:24:45.981: E/SQLiteDatabase(14495):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:209)
07-25 10:24:45.981: E/SQLiteDatabase(14495):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:193)
07-25 10:24:45.981: E/SQLiteDatabase(14495):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
07-25 10:24:45.981: E/SQLiteDatabase(14495):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
07-25 10:24:45.981: E/SQLiteDatabase(14495):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
07-25 10:24:45.981: E/SQLiteDatabase(14495):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:804)
07-25 10:24:45.981: E/SQLiteDatabase(14495):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:789)
07-25 10:24:45.981: E/SQLiteDatabase(14495):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:694)
07-25 10:24:45.981: E/SQLiteDatabase(14495):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:669)
07-25 10:24:45.981: E/SQLiteDatabase(14495):    at com.vivekwarde.indianconstitution.DBAdapter.checkDatabase(DBAdapter.java:44)
07-25 10:24:45.981: E/SQLiteDatabase(14495):    at com.vivekwarde.indianconstitution.ContentsFragment.onCreate(ContentsFragment.java:35)
07-25 10:24:45.981: E/SQLiteDatabase(14495):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1477)
07-25 10:24:45.981: E/SQLiteDatabase(14495):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:904)
07-25 10:24:45.981: E/SQLiteDatabase(14495):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1115)
07-25 10:24:45.981: E/SQLiteDatabase(14495):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
07-25 10:24:45.981: E/SQLiteDatabase(14495):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1478)
07-25 10:24:45.981: E/SQLiteDatabase(14495):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:446)
07-25 10:24:45.981: E/SQLiteDatabase(14495):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
07-25 10:24:45.981: E/SQLiteDatabase(14495):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-25 10:24:45.981: E/SQLiteDatabase(14495):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-25 10:24:45.981: E/SQLiteDatabase(14495):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4794)
07-25 10:24:45.981: E/SQLiteDatabase(14495):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-25 10:24:45.981: E/SQLiteDatabase(14495):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-25 10:24:45.981: E/SQLiteDatabase(14495):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
07-25 10:24:45.981: E/SQLiteDatabase(14495):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
07-25 10:24:45.981: E/SQLiteDatabase(14495):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-25 10:24:45.981: W/System.err(14495): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
07-25 10:24:45.991: W/System.err(14495):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
07-25 10:24:45.991: W/System.err(14495):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:209)
07-25 10:24:45.991: W/System.err(14495):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:193)
07-25 10:24:45.991: W/System.err(14495):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)    
07-25 10:24:45.991: W/System.err(14495):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
07-25 10:24:45.991: W/System.err(14495):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
07-25 10:24:45.991: W/System.err(14495):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:804)
07-25 10:24:45.991: W/System.err(14495):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:789)
07-25 10:24:45.991: W/System.err(14495):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:694)
07-25 10:24:45.991: W/System.err(14495):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:669)
07-25 10:24:45.991: W/System.err(14495):    at com.vivekwarde.indianconstitution.DBAdapter.checkDatabase(DBAdapter.java:44)
07-25 10:24:45.991: W/System.err(14495):    at com.vivekwarde.indianconstitution.ContentsFragment.onCreate(ContentsFragment.java:35)
07-25 10:24:45.991: W/System.err(14495):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1477)
07-25 10:24:45.991: W/System.err(14495):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:904)
07-25 10:24:45.991: W/System.err(14495):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1115)
07-25 10:24:46.001: W/System.err(14495):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
07-25 10:24:46.001: W/System.err(14495):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1478)
07-25 10:24:46.001: W/System.err(14495):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:446)
07-25 10:24:46.001: W/System.err(14495):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
07-25 10:24:46.001: W/System.err(14495):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-25 10:24:46.001: W/System.err(14495):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-25 10:24:46.001: W/System.err(14495):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4794)
07-25 10:24:46.001: W/System.err(14495):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-25 10:24:46.001: W/System.err(14495):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-25 10:24:46.001: W/System.err(14495):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
07-25 10:24:46.001: W/System.err(14495):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
07-25 10:24:46.001: W/System.err(14495):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-25 10:24:49.081: I/Choreographer(14495): Skipped 174 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Comment: What is line number "22" in SchedulesAdapter.java class?

Comment: Where are you creating the table? Actually its not the correct way, that you are using helper class. [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-sqlite-database-with-multiple-tables/)

Comment: @SiddharthVyas Data could not be fetched. So, In line no. 22 i am fetching the data from arraylist, so null pointer exception. If no such table problem is solved then the problem of nullpointerexception will also vanish !!

Comment: @Nizam I am fetching data from sqlite which is in assets folder, I dont have to insert data in database, so I left it blank. The link you provided creates the database at runtime ! but in my case the database is already created before running the app

Comment: Just a guess but don't hard code your paths. In your DBAdapter constructor replace to `path = v.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).getParent();`

Comment: I would suggest using [SQLiteAssetHelper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) instead of this custom code, seems to match your needs perfectly.

Comment: I think your problem is because the method onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) is called automaticaly when creating the database and this method is empty.

Comment: I updated my question, see my logcat, it shows exception in jelly bean related to sqliteconnectionpool but working fine

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, however the issue turned out not be related to the database but rather memory usage in the app. Older 2.3 devices understandably have less memory on them as well and depending on the environment users are running their devices on, your app may come up against memory constraints.

If I read the comments properly, you're coping a bundled sqlite db from your assets folder, if you can't reproduce the issue, it may be because your users don't have enough RAM available to your app or even have enough disk space to copy your DB.

`largeHeap` in your manifest only works on Android 3.0+ I believe so even if you have that set it won't solve the problem for older phones. I know the conventional wisdom is that Android app have 40mb of heap space initially, but my research suggests that this is a recommended size and not guaranteed, I've come across pre-honeycomb devices (sony in particular) that have as little as 20MB available to them.

In short, I suspect this is a memory issue and not one with the database. Try to come up with an alternate lighter weight strategy for 2.3 and below devices and see if the problem continues.

Comment: I think you are right, could be the problem related memory, as I am using main thread to fetch data, but its working fine in 2.3.3 emulator. I think I should compromise my app to minsdk 2.3.3

Comment: Emulators can be misleading. Look at the logcat while using your app, if the heap size keeps growing while you use it, there could be a memory issue. In particular i would look at the heap size and free space just after you launch the app.

Comment: I updated my question, see my logcat, it shows exception in jelly bean related to sqliteconnectionpool but working fine

Comment: have you tried to determine whether your first read happens / write to the DB happens before the copy of the DB is complete? The case could be on slow devices that the DB takes long to copy. This is a double edged sword on slow devices the DB may not have been copied and hence the issue where as in faster devices the read/write and copy may happen in parallel since you can get an error like this.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to change extension of you database to mp3 to avoid compression problems. Read [this](http://ponystyle.com/blog/2010/03/26/dealing-with-asset-compression-in-android-apps/) for further info. This behavior changes since 2.3 so it looks like it could help

Comment: its working fine in 2.3.3 emulator. I think I should compromise my app to minsdk 2.3.3

Comment: my sqlite stze is 1.59mb

Comment: I updated my question, see my logcat, it shows exception in jelly bean related to sqliteconnectionpool but working fine