# No Such Table Error ,what do i do? APP CRASH ON LAUNCH

Tags: android, sqlite, android-layout, android-studio

I've been having a major Issue with my code I think my table in my database is fine I've got three columns  _id, jobNM, JobDetails  and i've been over everything for weeks and I'm back to this same problem.  I'm getting  “Unable to start activity ComponentInfo” and in the Logcat it says “ Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: job (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT jobNM FROM job”.   I've got all my code below and the logcat as well any idea?

[EDIT]
here are some pictures of the db  DB browser for sqlite as well as the file path

db layout
[image]

file path

[image]

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    IntDataBaseHelper intDataBaseHelper;

    ListView lstJob;
    ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;





   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       intDataBaseHelper  = new IntDataBaseHelper(this);

        /*create instance of db helper and jobs
        Create the database (only if it doesn't exists)
        does so by copying from the assets */
       lstJob = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstJob);
        LoadJobList();
        if (CopyDBFromAssets.createDataBase(this,IntDataBaseHelper.DB_TABLE)) {
           // problem area
           // Get the data from the database

        ArrayList<String> jobs =  intDataBaseHelper.getJobList();
           for (String s : jobs) {
               Log.d("JobList ", "Found Job " + s);
              }
           } else {
               throw new RuntimeException("No Usable Database exists or was copied from the assets.");
           }

       }
      // loads job to screen
          public void LoadJobList() {
          ArrayList<String> JobList = intDataBaseHelper.getJobList();
          if (mAdapter == null) {
              mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,R.layout.header,R.id.header);
              mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,R.layout.row,R.id.BtnComplete,JobList);
              mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.row, R.id.Job_name,JobList);
              lstJob.setAdapter(mAdapter);
          } else
              {
              mAdapter.clear();
              mAdapter.addAll(JobList);
              mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
          }
      }

}
```

IntDataBase

```
public class IntDataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{


   private static  String DB_PATH ="/data/data/com.example.joelg.clapp/databases";
   public static  String DB_NAME = "JobList";
   public static  String DB_COLUMN = "jobNM";
   public static  String DB_TABLE = "job";
   private static  String DB_JOB_DETAILS = "jobDetails";
   private static  String DB_ISDONE = "jobIsDone";
   private  Context jobContext;
   private SQLiteDatabase JobListDatabase;




       /**
        * constructor creater
        */
       public IntDataBaseHelper (Context context) {
           super (context, DB_NAME,null, 1);
           this.jobContext = context;
           DB_PATH = jobContext.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).getPath();
       }


       public void OpenDataBase() {
           // open the database
           String JobListPath = DB_PATH;
           JobListDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(JobListPath,null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
       }


       // Getting Job Count
       public  ArrayList<String> getJobList() {
           ArrayList<String> JobList = new ArrayList<>();
           SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
           Cursor cursor =  db.query(DB_TABLE,new String[]
                   {DB_COLUMN},null,null,null,null,null);
               while(cursor.moveToNext()){
               int index = cursor.getColumnIndex(DB_COLUMN);
               JobList.add(cursor.getString(index));
           }

           cursor.close();
           db.close();
           return JobList;
       }


       // Gets the job state if it has been competed or not
   public ArrayList<String> getIsDone() {
       ArrayList<String>  IsDone = new ArrayList<>();
       SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
       Cursor cursor = db.query(DB_TABLE,new String[]{DB_ISDONE},null,null,null,null,null);
       while(cursor.moveToNext()){
           int index = cursor.getColumnIndex(DB_ISDONE);
           IsDone.add(cursor.getString(index));
       }

       cursor.close();
       db.close();
       return IsDone;
   }




       @Override
       public synchronized void close(){

           if(JobListDatabase !=null){
               JobListDatabase.close();
               super.close();

           }
       }
       @Override
       public  void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

       }
       @Override
       public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
       }
   }
```

LogCat

```
11-08 04:13:20.874 13790-13790/com.example.joelg.clapp E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such table: job
11-08 04:13:20.876 13790-13790/com.example.joelg.clapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTIO:main
Process: com.example.joelg.clapp, PID: 13790
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.joelg.clapp/com.example.joelg.clapp.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException:no such table: job (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT jobNM FROM job
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
       Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: job (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT jobNM FROM job
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1318)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1165)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1036)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1204)
    at com.example.joelg.clapp.IntDataBaseHelper.getJobList(IntDataBaseHelper.java:52)
    at com.example.joelg.clapp.MainActivity.LoadJobList(MainActivity.java:47)
    at com.example.joelg.clapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:31)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Comment: Uninstall your app and install again

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: (code 1) Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24634116/caused-by-android-database-sqlite-sqliteexception-no-such-table-code-1-andr)

Comment: i have already uninstalled and reinstalled and it's not a duplicate the app is not working on any device

Comment: i cannot see OpenDataBase() method. You didn't call the OpenDataBase() in your helper class before selection

Comment: You should have uses [SQLiteAssetHelper](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-sqlite-asset-helper/).

Comment: If you did updated your app, it could read the old SQLite file, I had exactly same issue before, and I solved it by change SQLite file to a new file name.

Comment: Iv deleted all the DB files and I'm going to create a new one from scratch I should be putting it in my assets file?

Comment: ok no luck there i cleared out all the databases and it cant find The job list table stille

Comment: Had you rename your DB file ?

Comment: I renamed it to masterList in the DB_NAME string and the actual file and no luck.

Comment: Can you try to dump that DB file from phone ?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4452538/location-of-sqlite-database-on-the-device/13154281#13154281

Comment: mm i don't thinks so the devices i need it to work for don't support and sd card

Comment: You still can dump DB file into your phone's internal storage, like "download" folder...

Comment: @RRTW  isnt that where private static  String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.example.joelg.clapp/databases";  does ?

Comment: That's SOURCE path, you can define your own TARGET path to any other accessible folder.

Answer (score 0):

Using SQL-Lite explorer check whether the table exist or not, meaning is there even a table

Comment: thats what i made the db in it is there

Comment: I added images of were everything is located

Answer (score 0):

I have started my app over it was getting to complicated and messy and i realised that i had the database path wrong